# How to build a DAO with elected leaders

Tags: solidity, contract-development, dao

I'm trying to build a DAO. It will work like this.

- Based on an ERC-20 token
- Holding the ERC-20 let's you vote for investors
- There will be 20 investors in total
- Investors are broken down into smaller sub-units (specializing in DeFi, NFTs, etc)
- Investors vote in their sub-unit how to allocate treasury funds for the highest ROI
- The DAO holds new elections every 6 months & can replace old investors in a trustless way

Where can I find tooling that would enable me to do this? I've looked into [Orca Protocol's Pods](https://orca.mirror.xyz/Y2xvPmB4cJH51srGqY6Mm_g38lV-7cwvtyDePnyzfAE), but that's still in private beta. Any ideas on how to bring this to life?

Answer (score 0):

You can use open Zeppelin.

It has Governance contracts for your voting mechanism.

The voting mechanism supports an ERC20Vote where the weight of the vote of the user is based on how many tokens he holds.

There are multiple types of tokens besides ERC20, like ERC721 for NFT tokens or ERC1155 for multiple tokens.

There is also the Ownable contract that helps you divide your users into roles, and set some functions only accessible for specific roles.

You can use their wizard to automatically create your contracts
https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/wizard